# int() or dict for single digit string to int conversions

Tags: python-3.x, string, type-conversion, int

I am trying to convert a single-digit string to an integer. For example, if I have `"2" <-- str` I want to change it to `2 <-- int`. I know that the `int()` function in python can do this for me, but I want to know if I made a dictionary like this,

```
strToNumDict{
  "0": 0
  "1": 1
  "2": 2
  "3": 3
  "4": 4
  "5": 5
  "6": 6
  "7": 7
  "8": 8
  "9": 9
}
```

Would using this dictionary to convert single digits be faster than the `int()` function? And if one is faster, is it fast enough to make a difference on which one I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a quick `timeit` benchmark. We generate at random one digit and will try to convert it to integer (x 1_000_000 times):

```
strToNumDict = {
  "0": 0,
  "1": 1,
  "2": 2,
  "3": 3,
  "4": 4,
  "5": 5,
  "6": 6,
  "7": 7,
  "8": 8,
  "9": 9
}

def convert1(s):
    return strToNumDict[s]

def convert2(s):
    return int(s)

import timeit
import random

digits = list('0123456789')

t1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: convert1(random.choice(digits)), number=1_000_000)
t2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: convert2(random.choice(digits)), number=1_000_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 2400G, Python 3.6.8):

```
0.6220340259897057
0.727682675991673
```

So dict-based version is *marginally* faster in this case. Personally, not worth the effort. With `int()` you get conversion from negative numbers, more than number 9 etc. And it's more readable.

Comment: `int` also implicitly strips leading and trailing whitespace, can be provided a base to handle binary, octal or hex strings, etc.

Comment: Are the times you got in milliseconds?

Comment: @EricXue `timeit` returns time in seconds as float https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.timeit